# Not sure how to handle the error "unexpected token"

Tags: jestjs, babeljs, babel-jest

I am trying to apply jest to the react-redux code, but now I am stuck in the env setting. It seems that the error has something to do with babel. Despite much information on the internet about "unexpected token", I still can't solve the issue. My settings are listed for reference.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

[image]

scripts in package.json (I use "npm run test" to start tests),

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:clear": "jest --clearCache"
  },
```

babel section shows bellow,

```
  "babel": {
    "env": {
      "test": {
        "presets": [
          "env"
        ],
        "only": [
          "./**/*.js",
          "node_modules/jest-runtime"
        ]
      }
    },
  }
```

devDependencies (all things related to babel are here)

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.4.4",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-jest": "^24.8.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "bili": "^4.8.0",
    "jest": "^24.8.0",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.2"
  },
```

jest section,

```
  "jest": {
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "<rootDir>/__tests__/setup/setupEnzyme.js"
    ],
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/__tests__/setup/"
    ]
  },
```

Comment: Can you post `jest` section also from `package.json` file?

Comment: does you `package.json` includes `@babel/runtime` in `dependencies` or `devDependencies` section?

Comment: I do. I also listed dependencies related to babel in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refered to https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-set-up-jest-enzyme-like-a-boss-8455a2bc6d56/ to build env up. Errors may have something to do with hidden config files.